# Videos in JQuery Cycle Plugin call stop event

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, jquery-events

I'm running a very simple cycle with some you tube video's the cycle is just :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#cycle').cycle({
            fx: 'fade',
            speed: 1000,
            pause: 1 
        });
    });
</script>
```

I want the user action of clicking the video to call:

```
$('#slideshow').cycle('stop');
```

Or some alternative method of allowing them to watch the video, I do not want to use manual navigators, (i.e. 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 buttons). How would I go about setting up that event? I'm trying to learn JavaScript, I generally do more client side. Or alternatively if this can't be done to link to new page with the video?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
$('#slideshow').click(function(){ $(this).cycle('stop'); });
```

You will have to NOT use the iframe code to embed your youtube videos because the iframe will prevent the click from propagating up into the main document.

Comment: Hmm ... tried something similiar '        $('#feature').click(function () {
            $('#cycle').cycle('stop'); 
        });' but when I click the movie it refreshes the page and restartes the cycle.  However, if I just click on the frame it will stop the carousel.  How do I handle the video playing event ?

Comment: www.allhipreplacementrecall.com ... It started a a plugin with navigation but I want to have it cycle all the videos until clicked

Comment: Given the setup of your page it should be $('#cycle').click(function(){ $(this).cycle('stop'); });

Comment: Thanks the problem is with was with how I thought the function was called.  I still can't get onclick="stop();" to work but I can get onmousehove="stop();" to work I guess that should work ...